# DAX - CALCULATING MAX Value of MEASURE in filtered Context

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerpivot

I have an issue that I am trying to solve with no luck yet
I have a table to which I have to calculate Max value of a MEASURE in overall report Context

Here is attached sample of data and a result that I should get
A measure for "Sum of NUM":

`Sum of NUM:=SUM(Data[NUM])`

I've tried maxx function in different variations, the best I am getting the same value as a total

Maxx_calc Measure:

`Maxx_Calc:=MAXX(SUMMARIZE('Data','Date'[Year],"Total Date Qty", SUM(Data[NUM])),[Total Date Qty])`

However the needed result is in the last column, I just can't get that calculation

any help will be much apreciated!
thanks in advance
[image: dax measure max of measure]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Measure = CALCULATE(SUM(_tx[val]),FILTER(_tx,_tx[cat ]="test"))
Measure 2 = CALCULATE(MAXX(GROUPBY(FILTER(_tx,_tx[cat ]="test"),_tx[p],"x",SUMX(CURRENTGROUP(),_tx[val])),[x]),ALL(_tx[p]))
```

[image: solution]

Comment: Thank you, had to tweak parts of it. The only question that I hav, is it possible to get this calculation without hardcoding?

Comment: You can simply use this `Measure:= CALCULATE(MAXX(GROUPBY(_tx,_tx[P],"x",SUMX(CURRENTGROUP(),_tx[val])),[x]),ALL(_tx[p]))`